# Python script loop to assign timeslot to each line in input file

Tags: python, python-2.7, time

I have a Python script that runs through a for-loop taking a list of `urls` as input. I want to be able to **stagger/randomise** the sequence of the `urls` and run them over the course of 1 hour.

Is it possible to read the file, assign a value in seconds to each of them and then start a counter, once the counter reaches the timeslot it triggers the script for that particular line in the file?

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on the help below I created this script to test the num.txt has a list of letters in it and I tested the script over 60 seconds rather than 1 hour.

```
f = open('num.txt')
url = f.readlines()
x=random.sample(xrange(60), 60)
i=0
for u in url:
time.sleep(x[i])
print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), u
i+=1
time.sleep(x[i])
```

And the output is `18:25:19 a 18:26:00 b 18:26:35 c 18:27:01 d 18:27:43 e 18:27:56 f`

What I want to do is assign a timeslot to  each of the letters randomly so for example `a = 44 b = 57 c = 12 d = 30 e = 22 f = 48`

So when the script starts a counter starts timing in seconds and once the time assigned to each of the letters is met they are ran through the loop so the for example `c` would run through the loop at 12 seconds, `e` at 22 seconds etc etc does that make sense?

Comment: You can use `time.sleep()` to halt the execution

Comment: Will it sleep each value in the loop and then run then when the time has elapsed? I don't want to run the first value and sleep up to 1 hour then run the second and sleep up to 1 hour.... I want to sleep all of them within a random period of 1 hour and run when that time is reached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852241/python-script-loop-to-assign-timeslot-to-each-line-in-input-file/29852366#comment47830619_29852241):

> *"I want to sleep all of them within a random period of 1 hour and run when that time is reached"*

**EDIT #1:**

I think you mean something like this, using [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep):

```
import time,random

x=random.sample(xrange(3600), 3600) #create randomly ordered list of size 3600 

i=0

for url in urls:
    time.sleep(x[i])   #sleep for a random value between (0 to 3600)
    i+=1               #increment 'i' by 1

time.sleep(sum(x[i:]))  #sum the rest of the values
```

***Explanation:***

So basically, `random.sample()` creates a *randomly ordered* list with all the numbers between 0-3600. Then, in the for-loop, `time.sleep()` takes a unique value of the list for every iteration. So for the 1st iteration, the first element of the list is used, for the 2nd iteration, the second element is used etc.

Then, after the for-loop is executed, you can use `sum()` with the slice notation `x[i:]` to add the rest of the values of the list, and then use `time.sleep()` to sleep for the remaining time.

---

**EDIT #2:**

For your updated example try this:

```
import random
import time

x=random.sample(xrange(60), 60) #create randomly ordered list of 1s with size 60  

d={}  #create empty dictionary                         
i=0

with open('data.txt') as f:
    for letter in f:
        letter=letter.rstrip()
        d[letter]=x[i]    #assign timeslots to letters
        i+=1

print d    #print dictionary 

j=1
with open('data.txt') as f:
    while j<=60:
        time.sleep(1)     #sleep for one second
        for key, value in d.items():  #check if the timeslots are reached
            if value == j:
                print key, j
        j+=1
```

If your **num.txt** file is like this:

```
a 
b 
c 
d 
e 
f
```

This code would output:

```
>>> 
{'a': 55, 'c': 37, 'b': 18, 'e': 23, 'd': 50, 'f': 33}
b 18
e 23
f 33
c 37
d 50
a 55
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question,
Why don't load the file into a list first with:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```